# Where is runtime library crti.o on solaris 7?

Tags: solaris, crt

I know there exist crti.o crt1.o crtn.o in /usr/lib on Solaris 10.
But these files are absent on Solaris 7.

Answer (score 1):

These files should be included with the compiler, under the same installation directory.  If you are using the Sun compiler check under `/opt/SUNWspro/lib/`; for gcc look under `/usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/`.  The exact directory depends on the version of the compiler, the platform architecture, and your installation options.  Normally the compiler will link this object into your program automatically, if you are producing an executable file as output.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is likely due to Solaris 7 not bundling a C compiler unlike Solaris 10. These files are C runtime objects only required when you need to link new executables.